# Find and sum multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, conditional-statements, worksheet-function

I can't sum multiple values. I use:

```
=INDEX(AdNetwork1!B:F,(MATCH(A1,AdNetwork1!B:B,0)-3),3)
```

but it finds only the first value. As you can see I use MATCH with `-3` to go up three rows and then move right three columns.

[image: SO27914388 question example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try something like:

```
=SUMIF(AdNetwork1!B4:B404,A1,AdNetwork1!D1:D401)
```

The ranges need to be the same size but may be offset for both column and row.

Comment: @Jeeped absolutely agree that would it would be better to explicitly match the range sizes.....but the formula, as written will still add D401 to the total if B404 = A1, because SUMIF always implicitly makes the sum range the same size and shape as the critera range

Comment: @barryhoudini - Good point and one that I was previously unaware of. Thanks! I've never used that principle for something like `=SUMIF(B4:B404, A1, D1)` but I may in the future.

Comment: There are other implications, though. If the range sizes aren't matched I believe that the formula becomes volatile, to some extent at least.

Comment: @barry houdini: That last point re volatility is very interesting. Is this documented somewhere? Are we talking about "volatile at workbook open only", as is the case for e.g. INDEX constructions using range references generated using ":"?

Comment: @barryhoudini It worked, but can somebody explain how 'SUMIF' pick right number from 'D1:D400?' Like if there was more than one number ?

Comment: @Macb3th - there's a `1 to 1` relationship between the criteria and sum ranges, if B4 = A1, `D1` is added to the sum, if B5 = A1 `D2` is added to the sum, if B6 = A1, `D3` is added to the sum....and so on, so it's always the cell 2 columns to the right and 3 up from each match

Comment: @XOR LX - re volatility of SUMIF - see this link http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsi.htm

Comment: ......I couldn't remember whether it was like `INDEX` or not, seems that `SUMIF` without matching range sizes is "properly volatile", so best avoided, although if there was a degree of complexity in defining the range it might be worth it